# Have main account email :fail: in Exim

Tags: email, exim

The main user account for a web server (domain@domain.com) is not used for email at all, but receives a lot of spam. I'd like these messages to just :fail:. I've tried adding a .forward file for the account with ":fail:" in it and emails to the account are bouncing instead of failing. The email is processed by the server instead of being rejected at the SMTP negotiation. I can confirm that this rejection works as it should if you try to email a fully non-existent user (no-account-here@domain.com)

Is there a way, I can get email to the main account to fail at the SMTP negotiation? We are using Linux with a DirectAdmin install and Exim.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't known how DirectAdmin manages the exim configuration, but it should be easy to modify the configuration to drop all emails **to** domain@domain.com with an ACL like:

```
acl_check_rcpt:
  . . . 
  drop
    log_message = matches domain@domain.com
    recipients = /etc/exim4/filters/recipients_drop.list
  . . .
```

and then put *domain@domain.com* (and, if needed, others addresses which should not receive mail) into the file `/etc/exim4/filters/recipients_drop.list`